# JAXB inheritance issue - namespace corruption

Tags: java, xml, inheritance, namespaces, jaxb

We're facing an issue when marshalling an object to xml with JAXB. In our code example (**https://github.com/fbe/JaxbIssueTracker**, simple maven project, test-case demonstrates what's going wrong) we have three types:

- parent
- hijacked
- concrete

**XSDs can be found here: [github](https://github.com/fbe/JaxbIssueTracker/tree/a4df9bd53d803cb078d3982336a012ae1fc9f1a5/src/main/resources)**

The parent type is abstract, concrete extends the parent, parent references the hijacked type in a sequence. From these xsd-files the JAVA files are being generated by JAXB (xjc) without any warn- or error-messages.

When marshalling a concrete type the following xml-output is being generated by JAXB:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns3:concreteType xmlns:ns2="http://www.felixbecker.name/parent" xmlns="http://www.felixbecker.name/hijacked" xmlns:ns3="http://www.felixbecker.name/concrete">
    <ns2:hijacked>
        <value>foobar</value>
    </ns2:hijacked>
</ns3:concreteType>
```

As you can see the hijacked-type is falsely using the ns2-prefix which refers to the namespace of the parent type - but instead it should use the default namespace which refers to the hijacked namespace.

JAXB is not able to unmarshal this generated xml although it is generated by itself with activated schema validation.

What is going wrong here? Is the xml-schema broken? Or is JAXB not able to deal with inheritance correctly?

Removing the abstract-attribute from the parent.xsd did not have any effect on the faced issue.

Any help would be highly appreciated! :-)

Used versions (both broken):

- JAXB from JDK 1.6
- JAXB-RI 2.2.5

Regards,

fbe & ollinux

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the `hijacked` **element** is actually defined in the parent schema and so gets placed in the "parent" namespace. This means the namespaces of the marshalled document are correct. If jaxb can unmarshal the document it itself marshalled then this sounds like a bug to me.

To get the `hijacked` element in the correct namespace you could move the element declaration to the `hijacked` schema and use

```
<element ref="hijacked:hijacked"/>
```

in the parent schema.